# Function for which trapezoidal rule outperforms midpoint rule for every $n$

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation, approximation-theory

Is there a continuous [elementary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ such that for every $n$ the trapezoidal approximation to $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ with $n$ trapezoids is strictly better than the midpoint approximation with $n$ rectangles?

The point of this questions is that even though the midpoint approximation to an integral is generally better than the trapezoidal approximation, there is, for each $n$, a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ such that the trapezoidal approximation to $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx$ with $n$ trapezoids is better than the midpoint approximation with $n$ rectangles. See [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~heffernan/math1132s13/files/trapezoid_rule.pdf) for an example.

I added the restriction that $f$ be elementary so I can talk about the answer with my calculus students. I added the restriction that $f$ be non-negative for simplicity.

Comment: I can't help with your question, but I find it curious in your link the author claimed there was no antiderivitive of $\frac 1 x$.   Strange.

Comment: What does the author mean when writing that "we have never come across a function whose derivative is $\frac1x$"?

Comment: @Alan Actually he only claimed that they'd "never come across a function whose derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$". I suppose this means they've not defined the natural log yet.

Comment: Hmm, so is it calculus limited to polynomials? Sounds like the precalculus was badly neglected in that class ;)

Comment: Ahh,  yes.   Beginning calculus.   Silly folks,  just do what we do in analysis and define the natural log as that integral function :).

Comment: @MPW Not it's not necessarily calculus limited to polynomials. They've evidently just not gotten to natural log yet.

Comment: @Alan Maybe they will do that (we did that in the class I'm teaching now). But approximations can just as well come before that.

Comment: @QuinnCulver: Yes, I'm teasing to a large extent

Comment: Consider functions whose definite integrals represent the area of a trapezoid (or triangle).

Comment: @user170231 Would you please elaborate? If the function is a line (so it's definite integral represents the area of a trapezoid), then I think the trapezoidal and midpoint approximations are always the same.

Comment: Here's one where at least midpoint isn't always better. In fact the choice of lowest error method fluctuates in an oscillatory way with n: f(x)=$\sqrt{|\tan(\pi x)|}$.

Comment: If a function is piecewise $C^2$, the midpoint will  beat trapezoid for large $n$. Do you know any continuous elementary function that is not piecewise $C^2$? I don't. The function in the answer by Robert Israel is about as simple as continuous nowhere differentiable functions get.

Comment: @CareBear: Piecewise $C^2$ is not sufficient.  Let  $f(x)=a-x$ for $x\le a$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \ge a$, for a fixed irrational $a\in (0,1)$.  For some $n$ the midpoint rule is better; for others the trapezoidal rule is better; but it goes back and forth as $n$ increases, depending on where $a$ lies in its "bin".

Comment: @mjqxxxx Good point; what I had in mind should work for piecewise $C^2$ that is *not* piecewise linear.

Comment: A late comment - but Robert Israel's example **is** smooth. It's not just $C^2$, but $C^{\infty}$ and even analytic. See also this [AoPS post](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h262240p1430408) of mine with a very similar example.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a function of the form
$$ f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j \cos(2  \pi j x) $$
Then the errors $ME(n)$ and $TE(n)$ in midpoint and trapezoid rules are
$$\eqalign{TE(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_{kn} \cr
           ME(n) &= 2 TE(2n) - TE(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k} c_{kn} \cr}$$
For example, let $c_j = (-1)^{d(j)} 2^{-j}$ where $d(j)$ is the $2$-adic order of $j$, i.e. $d(j) = d$ if $2^d$ divides $j$ but $2^{d+1}$ does not.
Then if $d(n) = d$ we have
$$ \eqalign{TE(n) &= (-1)^d \left(\sum_{k\; odd} 2^{-kn} - \sum_{k\; odd} 2^{-2kn} + \sum_{k \; odd} 2^{-4kn} + \ldots\right)\cr
&= (-1)^d \left( \dfrac{2^{-n}}{1-4^{-n}} - \dfrac{2^{-2n}}{1-4^{-2n}} + \dfrac{2^{-4n}}{1-4^{-4n}} - \ldots \right)\cr } $$ 
while
$$ ME(n) = (-1)^{d+1} \left( \dfrac{2^{-n}}{1-4^{-n}} + \dfrac{2^{-2n}}{1-4^{-2n}} - \dfrac{2^{-4n}}{1-4^{-4n}} + \ldots \right) $$
so $|ME(n)| > |TE(n)|$.

Comment: Thanks. This is great, but doesn't answer what I actually intended to ask. I've updated my question correspondingly.

Comment: Hmm, well, it's not elementary, but it is the sum of a rapidly convergent series of elementary functions:
$$ \sum_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{(8^{2^j} - 2^{2^j}) \cos(2^{j+1} \pi x)}{16^{2^j} + 1 - 2 \cdot 4^{2^j} \cos(2^{j+2} \pi x)}$$
if I haven't made a mistake.

Comment: Perhaps a proof exists which shows the function asked for must be fuzzy like this one in order for trapezoid to out-perform midpoint.

Comment: What do you mean by fuzzy?